# Queue<byte> vs. Stream

Tags: c#, generics, stream, queue, byte

Is there an difference between a Queue and a Stream in C#?

Answer (score 9):

The question should be: do they even have anything in common besides both offering some sort of interface to retrieve bytes from?

A queue `Queue<byte>` is just that, a FIFO queue of bytes, main functionality is to enqueue or dequeue a single byte value at a time - there is no random access. You usually use a queue as part of a *data structure* or algorithm (i.e. breadth first search in a tree comes to mind). All data in a queue is stored in memory.

A stream on the other hand is an abstract representation of a byte stream usually obtained from a file, memory, network or other source - there is always an underlying source or target.This source doesn't have to be in memory, i.e. a network or file stream will allow you to read from or write to a file or network - so a stream is the main way to get bytes from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

A queue has to stores bytes, a stream doesn't.  Big difference.

Comment: Hans, in .NET a bare Stream only deals with `byte[]`. You need a Formatter/Writer to store something else.

Comment: Yup, side effect of a queue having to store stuff.  I'm just trying to highlight the biggest difference, there are too many.  Btw: wouldn't `Stream<T>` be awfully nice?

Answer (score -1):

Im not a C# (or even .NET) guy at all, and hopefully someone will provide a more detailed answer, but..

I think its pretty clear that `Queue` and `Stream` are quite different.  I understandwhy you'd ask, but even a quick peek at the API shows a lot of differences.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx

Foremost among these differences is that a Queue is part of Collections package and `Stream` is part of `IO`

EDIT - typed Queue is probably more applicable, as shown with other poster
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx